# Java converting int variable to String by adding an empty string?

Tags: java, android-studio

The second argument of the ***addFormDataPart*** call should be a string.

```
 int privacyLevel = 0;
 builder.addFormDataPart("privacy",privacyLevel);
```

However, since privacyLevel is an integer, it needs to be converted to String.

[image]
In the tutorial, he made the conversion by adding an empty String at the end of privacyLevel:

```
builder.addFormDataPart("privacy",privacyLevel+"");
```

I found this to be an unusual way of converting an int to string. And all the research I've done pointed me to traditional methods of conversion.
So does anyone have an explanation for this? 
And is this even a "good practice"?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a good practice, no. But it works and is easy to understand. Do you really need an explanation? It's just a string concatenation. You do it all the time with non-empty strings. It works the same way with empty ones.

Comment: I didn't know you can do a string concatenation with an int

Comment: Well, you can. You can concatenate a string with anything. The thing you're concatenating it with will be transformed to a String, and then concatenated. Have you really never used something like `System.out.println("My age is: " + age);`?

Comment: @JBNizet okay thanks

Comment: I did, but I didn't know it actually converts it into a String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the proper tool: `Integer.toString(int)`: this might be easier to read as it clearly show your intent on getting a `String` out of your `int`.

```
int privacyLevel = 0;
builder.addFormDataPart("privacy", Integer.toString(privacyLevel));
```

When you use:

```
builder.addFormDataPart("privacy", "" + privacyLevel);
```

You are creating a new String from `""` and `Integer.toString(privacyLevel)`, but there might be some optimization during compile time or at runtime:

- Compiler can detect the `""` and directly use `Integer.toString(privacyLevel)`.
- Compiler may replace the `+` operation by the `String::concat` method. Said method may return the other `String` when itself is empty, or return itself when the *other* `String` is empty (in openjdk 8u232, the method is actually checking the length of *other* and always perform a concatenation).

Now, to see what the compiler does, here is a simple code which does nothing extraordinary:

```
class Foobar {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1;
    String s = n + "";
  }
}
```

If you call `javap -p Foobar.class`, you can see what the compiler did (with Java 11.0.6, Java 8 use a `StringBuilder`):

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: (0x0009) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=3, args_size=1
         0: iconst_1
         1: istore_1
         2: iload_1
         3: invokedynamic #2,  0              // InvokeDynamic #0:makeConcatWithConstants:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
         8: astore_2
         9: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 8: 0
        line 9: 2
        line 10: 9
```

Using `Integer.toString` only change the `invokedynamic` to `invokestatic`:

```
3: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.toString:(I)Ljava/lang/String
```

The compiler does not try to be intelligent in this case and don't optimize `"" + int`.

If you read Javadoc of `java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory.makeConcatWithConstants(Lookup, String, MethodType, String, Object...)`, it references [JLS 15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) and [JLS 5.1.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11).

The [JLS 15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) explains the concatenation operation from *String + Not a String*:

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string
>   conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a
>   string at run time.

The [JLS 5.1.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11) explains how to convert an `int` to `String`:

> A value x of primitive type T is first converted to a reference value
>   as if by giving it as an argument to an appropriate class instance
>   creation expression (§15.9):
>
> ```
> If T is byte, short, or int, then use new Integer(x).
> ```

To answer your question:

> I found this to be an unusual way of converting an int to string. And all the research
>   I've done pointed me to traditional methods of conversion.
>   So does anyone have an explanation for this? And is this even a "good practice"?

What's unusual in your case if the fact the String is after the number, rather than before (as in `"privacyLevel: " + privacyLevel`), but that is not strange given the [JLS 15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1).

I could not say it is a good practice, even though it is relative, but I'd say it is *legacy* practice born for the fact that `Integer.toString` is not so old (I can't remember if it was added in Java 5 or 6) and that the easier way was to doing `n + ""` or `"" + n`.

I would personally favor `Integer.toString` because I find `n + ""` rather ugly. It might also be better in terms of performance due to the complexity of the conversion done otherwise. Luckily for you or my answer, someone did a [JMH benchmark](https://gist.github.com/ecki/399136f4fd59c1d110c1).

Last but not least, if you stick with concatenation, the result will depends on the version of compiler which will do the actual transformation:

- You are using Android Studio, and what apply to vanilla Java may not completely apply here.
- Java 8 use a `StringBuilder` to generate an int' String.
- Java 11 use `invokedynamic` and a lot of stuff harder (for me) to explain, but I assume it does its job and perform as well, if better, than `StringBuilder`.
- `Integer.toString` seems to be optimized in newer hotspot JVM (it is annotated `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` in Java 13).